# Migration to Spring WS 2.0 failed due to lack of bean endpoint mapping?

Tags: java, spring, spring-ws

We used the `PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping` to map endpoint scripts (based on a scripting language like groovy or something else) to a given root `QName`. We recently tried to migrate spring ws to version 2.0. The javadoc of the [PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping.html) shows that the class is marked as deprecated.

> `PayloadRootQNameEndpointMapping` Deprecated as of Spring Web Services 2.0, in favor of `PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping`

Since annotations are static we can't provide a dynamic concept for scripting endpoints. Until now we could generically map the Bean which is handling a script endpoint (provided with a script file and some contexts) to the root `QName`.

**Short**: How can we achieve the good old bean endpoint to Root QName mapping without using the deprecated API? Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use something like the [SimpleMethodEndpointMapping](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/SimpleMethodEndpointMapping.java.html) to write your own dispatcher? Check the link for the source

Comment: Yes, I wrote my own dispatcher for this. I also now generate the bean configuration, not a best practice though =/

Answer (score -1):

You can use more general [XPathPayloadEndpointMapping](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/server/endpoint/mapping/XPathPayloadEndpointMapping.html) where xpath will point to root element.

```
<bean id="endpointMapping" class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.XPathPayloadEndpointMapping">
    <property name="expression" value="local-name(//*[1])" />
    <property name="endpointMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="rootElement" value="endpointRef" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```